# making two vectors the same length using interpolatoin in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, interpolation

i want to interpolate a vector y1 of length 3  to get a vector y2 of length 6.which of  the functions interp1 or resample should i use?

ex.
y1=[1 2 3];
y2=[1 2 3 4 5 6 ];

resample(y1,length(y2),length(y1))

Comment: If you want to interpolate, you probably should use a function that interpolates.

Answer (score 2):

Use `interp1`.

Ex: You have a sinusoidal signal sampled every pi/4.

```
x = 0:pi/4:2*pi;
v = sin(x);
```

[image]

Now to want a finer sampling `xq` (every pi/16):

```
xq = 0:pi/16:2*pi;
```

The result will be:

```
vq1 = interp1(x,v,xq);
```

[image]

Where `vq1` is a vector whose values are interpolated from `v`to satisfy the new sampling `xq`

PD: You can also pass as a parameter which type of interpolation you want: 'linear', 'nearest', 'cubic', etc...

Comment: In my example you also have numerical vectors. sin(x) is not a symbolic function, its just generating values, but if you follow a formula it's easier to see that the interpolation works. You can replace the `sin(x)` by `rand(numel(x),1)` and see that it still works.